# Add Lightbox Effect to NextGen Gallery Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Just can't seem to figure it out. How can I turn the lightbox effect on while using the Wordpress NextGen Gallery Plugin?

Answer (score 10):

Your answer was almost perfect, and certainly led me on the correct trail.

The Lightbox plugin to enable the Lightbox effect in NextGen Gallery is actually deprecated, and replaced by the Slimbox Plugin by my compatriot Giuseppe Argento.

The official WordPress page for the plugin is here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slimbox-plugin/

Just install the plugin, then, in the Gallery options, go to:

Gallery >> Options >> Effects

You can now choose "Lightbox," and it will work perfectly.

Just make sure that your images are not too big, as Lightbox/Slimbox does not resize images that come up in the modal layer above your Web page.

I usually shoot for a maximum size of 800 x 600.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking but:

> 3:  I didn’t get the Highslide or Lightbox effect working…
>   NextGEN Gallery supports only Shutter and Thickbox as full integrated effect. All other effects are possible but you need to add them manually. You can use other plugins to add the effect.
>   Highslide JS plugin or Lightbox JS Plugin

I found this @: 
http://alexrabe.boelinger.com/wordpress-plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/
(its Q #3)
linked from:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/

Comment: there are links on the http://alexrabe.boelinger.com/wordpress-plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/ page to the plugins mentioned